# Generating .ser files dynamically in the server where application is deployed

Tags: java, json, spring, weblogic

**Back ground :**
I am writing REST APIs for a spring based web application.War file of the project is deployed in weblogic server in a dedicated server space. My service 1 internally uses a object "X" (deep graphed object with many references of other objects).These services are getting called from front end.

**Requirement:** In another service "service 2" I need the exact same object "X".

**Constraint**: I cant reproduce the object, I cant ask front end guy to send me that inside JSON. Its such a huge object, its not a good idea to store it in Application Context level.

**My proposed Solution**: In service 1 after the object X is prepared I will be serializing it and store it in a serialized file in server. In service 2 I will de serialize and reproduce the object X.

**Challenges in Proposed Solution:**

- I am not sure storing file in a server is a good idea though file
  size is 1-2 kb.
- This file creation and serializing will be dynamic in the code. So in what path I will store the .ser file. ***How to get the path of the server dynamically ? What are the work arounds if its not possible to store the .ser file dynamically in server.***

Comment: Use a file server

Comment: Is there any other way , bcz currently we dont have a file server

Comment: First - it is possible. There is only one requirement - both Service1 and Service2 must use same jar file where your X class is.

Comment: Second: JMS subsystem is there to do not do those "save file"/"read file". Publish your object to the queue from Service1 and Listen that queue from Service2.

Comment: Third: SOA is all about that. Interface between Service1 and Service2 can be implemented in many ways and with many integration approaches: RMI/EJB, SOAP/REST through http, JMS, in-memory queue, or as you propose file system etc. There are many frameworks to do SOA - Camel, Mule, Spring Integration ... and so and so...